# I don't understand why "a"+6=24

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a student currently studying computer science and we are learning about try: and except: I have hit a wall on this question and i just cant figure it out.

> For this exercise you should define a function called `add_list_values()` which is passed a list of values as well as two index positions.  The function should return the sum of the two values at the specified index positions.
>
> For example, if the list is:
>
> ```
> myList = [4,2,6,7,8,1]
> ```
>
> then the function call:
>
> ```
> add_list_values(myList, 2, 4)
> ```
>
> should return the value 14.
>
> A couple of things could go wrong here.  Firstly, if a sequence subscript is out of range, then an `IndexError` will be generated.  And of course, unless both operands are numeric, then a `TypeError` will occur indicating that the the addition could not be completed.
>
> Define the `add_list_values()` function, taking into account these possible exceptions.  Please note:
>
> - If an `IndexError` occurs, then the function should return 0
> - If a `TypeError` occurs, then the function should return the string concatenation of the two values

for some reason, when I get to the second list instead of throwing an error, I get the answer (24)?

I want to know how I can check a list for strings, so I can identify this string and call the `TypeError`.

```
def add_list_values(myList, p1, p2):
    try:
        print (myList[p1])
        print (myList[p2])
        answer = myList[p1] + myList[p2]
        return answer

    except IndexError:
        return 0

    except TypeError:
        return str(p1)+str(p2)

#myList = [4,2,6,7,-2,100]
#print(add_list_values(myList, 2, 4))

myList = [4,2,6,7,"a",100]
print(add_list_values(myList, 2, 4))

#myList = [4,2,6,7,-6,100]
#print(add_list_values(myList, 2, -400))
```

Comment: still learning how this site works.....

Comment: @StudentincompsciNZ: please add the code to your answer (press "edit" link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating two indexes cast as strings when you `catch` the `TypeError` in the except:

```
return str(p1) + str(p2)
```

`p1` is 2 and  `p2`  is 4 so `str(2) + str(4)`   returns the string `24`

If you want to return the error:

```
except TypeError as e:
    return e
```

If you want to raise, you would need to use  `raise` not return

The whole idea of the try/except is to catch the `TypeError` and not raise an exception which is exactly what is happening, trying to add the string `"a"` to the int `6` does cause a TypeError which you catch and return the two indexes cast as str and concatenated.

Comment: @StudentincompsciNZ, no worries, we have al been there.